# Apache <Files> with Require to exempt certain Files

Tags: apache, authentication

I setup a .htaccess file to require authentication for a directory.  I would like to exempt certain files (csv) to avoid some issues with downloading.

I can limit the authentication to the files by doing:

```
<files ~ "\.csv$">
    require valid-user
</files>
```

But how can I negate(!) them so ALL files except csv files require authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<files ~ "\..*(?<!csv)$">
    require valid-user
</files>
```

I've tested this on my local server (Apache 2.2.14) and it works fine. All files except `.csv` files require authentication before downloading.

**Edit**
Sorry about all the edits. These sort of regular expressions are always tricky :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you access the directory directly.

Comment: How do you mean? (By that I mean; how do you access the directory *indirectly*?) - I've tried both of these and they should work. *(Note the edit in the post tho!)*

Comment: The original one would break by going to mydomain.com/dir/  This one seems to work though. Thanks!